# Can't find ASP.NET master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, scope, content-pages

I'm trying to get my content page to be able to access an ASP:Literal on a master page.

I have my content page as:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="viewProduct.aspx.cs" Inherits="AlphaPackSite.viewProduct" Title="Hi there!" %>
<%@ MasterType TypeName="Main" %>
```

Then my master page called Main.master has:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lblBasket" />
```

But from the content page when I try and do:

```
Master.basket.Text = "test";
```

I get:

> Error 46 The type or namespace name
>   'Main' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

The error is on the designer page:

```
public new Main Master {
    get {
        return ((Main)(base.Master));
    }
}
```

My master page code behind is:

```
namespace AlphaPack.MasterPages
{
    public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.IsLoggedIn = Request.IsAuthenticated;
        }

        public bool IsLoggedIn
        {
            get { return this.ViewState["isLoggedIn"] as bool? ?? false; }
            set { this.ViewState["isLoggedIn"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it makes a difference the master page is located in a different folder

Comment: <%@ MasterType TypeName="Main" VirtualPath="~MasterPages/Main.Master" %>  Doesn't seem to work either

Comment: btw, it's rather better to put auth check to `Page_Init` than `Page_Load`

Comment: Why you don't have MasterPageFile property in Page directive and no VirtualPath in MasterType?

Comment: I can access the master pages functions now, but I can't seem to access controls on the master page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the designer within your `AlphaPack.MasterPages` namespace?

The `MasterType` isn't fully qualified, should it be? Don't you have to provide a path as well? (Not familiar with, sorry).

How does this respond if you use a `MasterPageFile` reference instead of a `MasterType`?

Comment: I was told to use the master type so that I can access variables on the master page.

Comment: I put them all in the same namespace and intellisense lets me see Master. now, but I get Error    21    'AlphaPackSite.Main' does not contain a definition for 'lblBasket' and no extension method 'lblBasket' accepting a first argument of type 'AlphaPackSite.Main' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: ah I can access functions on the master page now, but just can't access the label directly?

Comment: Thanks, nearly there I think!  Even though the control exists on the master page it still can't find it:  'AlphaPackSite.Main' does not contain a definition for 'lblBasket' and no extension method 'lblBasket' accepting a first argument of type 'AlphaPackSite.Main' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The references to controls are contained in the designer, this very much sounds like the designer needs to be regenerated still, but note also that ''AlphaPackSite' is not 'AlphaPack.MasterPages' as I would expect based on your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~MasterPages/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="viewProduct.aspx.cs" Inherits="AlphaPackSite.viewProduct" Title="Hi there!" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Main.master" .. %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/Main.master" .. %>
```

Okey, that's how it looks in my own app:

Master page (Site.master, in the root):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Project.SiteMaster" %>
```

It's code-behind:

```
namespace Project
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage { } 
}
```

Content page (Test.aspx, in the root):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project.Test" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" Title="Test" %>
```

it's code-behind:

```
namespace Project
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page { }
}
```

That's how auto-generated code looks like:

```
namespace Project {
    public partial class SiteMaster {            
        /// <summary>
        /// lblBasket control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal lblBasket;
    }
}
```

So create a property but don't share the control itself, only text:

```
public string BasketText
{
    get { return this.lblBasket.Text; } 
    set { this.lblBasket.Text = value; }
}
```